# Linq - Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq, error-handling, implicit-conversion

I am receiving the following error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'Munchkin.Model.PlayerProfiles.Profile'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

My code is:

```
Profile currentProfile;

public Profile ActiveProfile()
{
    currentProfile = new Profile();        
    return currentProfile = 
        (from profiles in xmlDoc.Element("PlayerPofiles").Element("Online").Elements("Player")
        where (string)profiles.Element("Active") == "True"
        select new Profile
        {
            Name = (string)profiles.Element("Name"),
            Sex = (string)profiles.Element("Sex"),
            Avatar = (string)profiles.Element("Avatar").Attribute("path") ?? "",
            Created = (DateTime)profiles.Element("Created"),
            Birthday = (string)profiles.Element("Birthday"),
            Wins = (string)profiles.Element("Ratio").Element("Win"),
            Losses = (string)profiles.Element("Ratio").Element("Loss"),
            Abandoned = (string)profiles.Element("Ratio").Element("Abandoned")
        });
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public Profile ActiveProfile()
        {
            currentProfile = new Profile();

           return currentProfile = (from profiles in xmlDoc.Element("PlayerPofiles").Element("Online").Elements("Player")
                            where (string)profiles.Element("Active") == "True"
                            select new Profile
                              {
                                  Name = (string)profiles.Element("Name"),
                                  Sex = (string)profiles.Element("Sex"),
                                  Avatar = (string)profiles.Element("Avatar").Attribute("path") ?? "",
                                  Created = (DateTime)profiles.Element("Created"),
                                  Birthday = (string)profiles.Element("Birthday"),
                                  Wins = (string)profiles.Element("Ratio").Element("Win"),
                                  Losses = (string)profiles.Element("Ratio").Element("Loss"),
                                  Abandoned = (string)profiles.Element("Ratio").Element("Abandoned")
                              }).FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

As your currentProfile is Single Profile Item and query assign collection of profile that is why this error comes. Try to use **FirstOrDefault()**

Comment: Thanks Dotnetstep... that fixed it.

Comment: you should omit this line `currentProfile = new Profile();`, it is completely unnecessary, also the method should return `Profile`

Comment: Thanks @KrisIvanov - I'v'e removed the first line. I am confused though, why should it return Profile and not currentProfile?

Comment: my suggestion was to remove `currentProfile = new Profile();` line since the creation of `Profile` gets overwritten in the very next line